# dependency injection with partial controllers

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core

i have controller which is partial
and i want to add functionality to it
so i created another partial class for the controller
in first i want specefic services so i injected them in ctor
in second i want different services so i careated new ctor and injected services into it
but the second ctor never be hit so services in the scond controller still null and give me exception `object refernce not set to instance`
here is my code
this is  first partial

```
public partial class CommonController : BaseController
    {
       
        private readonly IStoreService _storeService;
 
 public CommonController(IStoreService storeService)
        {
            _storeService = storeService;
        }
}
```

and this is second partial

```
` public partial class CommonController : BaseController
    {
         public CommonController(
            CommonSettings commonSettings,
            ICommonModelFactory commonModelFactory)
       {
        _commonSettings = commonSettings;
            _commonModelFactory = commonModelFactory;
      }
           
    }
    `
```

Comment: How can this even compile? You can't inherit from two different base classed, even with partial classes.

Comment: i edited the question they inherit from same base but the qustion is how do dependency injection in this case  @DavidG

Comment: Controllers need a single constructor that explicitly injects all the required services.

Comment: @AhmedZakaria: See the following post: [Multiple constructor discovery rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/dependency-injection#multiple-constructor-discovery-rules). _**Your code with ambiguous DI-resolvable type parameters would throw an exception. Do not do this, it's intended to show what is meant by "ambiguous DI-resolvable types".**_

Comment: Multiple constructors don't run, it will pick a single one and run (or throw an exception perhaps)

Answer (score 0):

Your `partial` class should be like this:

```
public partial class CommonController 
{
           
}
```

You shouldn't inherit from another class and haven't a constructor in partial class